# C# if else logic error

Tags: c#, winforms

I doing some kind logic but its getting error?

here my code

```
private static void DrawText(String text, Font font, Color textColor, Color backColor)
{
    Image img = new Bitmap(640, 360);
    Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    Color color = textColor;
    if (text.Length <= 80) {
        Rectangle displayRectangle =
            new Rectangle(new Point(20, 100), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
    } else {
        Rectangle displayRectangle =
            new Rectangle(new Point(20, 80), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
    }
    StringFormat format1 = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
    StringFormat format2 = new StringFormat(format1);

     // ERROR ON NEXT LINE
    drawing.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Red, (RectangleF)displayRectangle, format2);

    drawing.Dispose();
    string fileName = "f.png";
    string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fileName);
    img.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    img.Dispose();
}
```

the error is

> Error 1 The name 'displayRectangle' does not exist in the current context C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008>\Projects\template\template\Form1.cs 119 69  template

At this line

```
drawing.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Red, (RectangleF)displayRectangle, format2);
```

In php the logic was right, but when in C# its getting error?, How doing this logic in C#?

Any help? ( Still learning C# by doing :D )

Comment: `displayRectangle` goes out of scope at the closing brace.  Declare it outside the if/else and simply assign it to the existing variable inside the if/else.

Comment: 3 Mins and 6 answers, people sure jumped on this one!

Comment: @all, thanks for the help, now I knew the "right way" creating logic in C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, it doesn't work that way :)

Variables defined within an `if` or an `else` block, between the `{` and the `}` are only visible in that block. That is why you were able to define it twice, once in the `if` branch and once in the `else` branch.

So the solution is to declare the variable before the branching, and just set it in the if/else branches.

```
Rectangle displayRectangle; //declaration

if (text.Length <= 80)
{
  //setting
  displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 100), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
}
else
{
  //setting
  displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 80), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
}
....
//usage
drawing.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Red, (RectangleF)displayRectangle, format2);
```

In addition, the C# compiler is smart enough to detect that the variable is set in each branch, so that it will definitely be set when it reaches it's usage code. However, if it's not set in every branch, that would be a compile error, e.g.

```
if (text.Length <= 80)
{
  displayRectangle = ...;
}
else if (text.Length > 40)
{

  displayRectangle = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Move the `Rectangle` definition above the `if` `else` block, so that it doesn't go out of scope.

```
Rectangle displayRectangle;

if (text.Length <= 80)
{
    displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 100), new Size(img.Width  img.Height - 1));
}
else
{
    displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 80), new Size(img.Width -  img.Height - 1));
}
```

Comment: No need to intialize (write `=null`) before the `if` since the value will be overwritten in all cases anyway (which the compiler can easily infer). ADDITION: If the `Rectangle` type is a `struct`, the value `null` isn't even allowed (seen in comments to other answers).

Answer (score 4):

You could define the `displayRectangle` variable outside of your if/else logic:

```
Rectangle displayRectangle;
if (text.Length <= 80)
{
    displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 100), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
}
else
{
    displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 80), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
}
```

Now this variable will be known to the outer scope.

Comment: if I do this, Iam getting this..

`Error 1 Cannot convert null to 'System.Drawing.Rectangle' because it is a non-nullable value type C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\template\template\Form1.cs 102 42 template`

Comment: Yeap indeed, `Rectangle` is a value type. See my update. No need to assign a value when declaring the variable because this variable is then assigned in an if/else logic.

Comment: Just don't assign `null` to it in the first place, or even a default value for that matter.  You're *going* to assign a value in the `if` block, so it needs no initial value.  Specifically excluding it draws attention to the fact that the initial value is never used; explicitly setting it implies you plan to use it in some code path.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a variable which is declared outside of the current scope. You have declared `displayRectangle` inside of the `if-clause`, hence it is "invisible" outside of it.

Instead declare it outside and initialize it inside:

```
Rectangle displayRectangle = Rectangle.Empty;
if (text.Length <= 80)
{
     displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 100), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
}
else
{
    displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 80), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
}
```

[8.5.1 Local variable declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> **The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration
>   is the block in which the declaration occurs**. It is an error to refer
>   to a local variable in a textual position that precedes the
>   local-variable-declarator of the local variable. Within the scope of a
>   local variable, it is a compile-time error to declare another local
>   variable or constant with the same name.

Comment: getting this errror

`Error 1 A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\template\template\Form1.cs 102 55 template`

Comment: His `Rectangle` is a `struct`, so you can't assign `null` to it in the beginning.

Comment: @TimSchmelter But you found a fancy name for `default(Rectangle)` I see :-) Personally, I leave the variable unassigned at the declaration in cases like this. But then I can't use the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Move your variable declaration outside the block:

```
    Rectangle displayRectangle;
    if (text.Length <= 80)
    {
        displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 100), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
    }
    else
    {
        displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 80), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
    }
```

The problem is the scope of displayRectangle in your code. As soon as the block is finished executing, displayRectangle is completely forgotten about since it's declared inside the block.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of your initialization.

The way it should be:

```
 private static void DrawText(String text, Font font, Color textColor, Color backColor)
 {
    Rectangle displayRectangle; // YOU MUST DECLARE IT HERE OR OUTSIDE THE FUNCTION,
                                // but never inside an "if" statement.
    Image img = new Bitmap(640, 360);
    Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    Color color = textColor;
    if (text.Length <= 80) {
        displayRectangle =
           new Rectangle(new Point(20, 100), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
    } else {
        displayRectangle =
           new Rectangle(new Point(20, 80), new Size(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1));
    }
    StringFormat format1 = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
    StringFormat format2 = new StringFormat(format1);

    // ERROR ON NEXT LINE
    drawing.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Red, (RectangleF)displayRectangle, format2);

    drawing.Dispose();
    string fileName = "f.png";
    string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fileName);
    img.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    img.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You seem to have mixed up "initialize" with "declare".  You need to "declare" it outside of the `if` statement, but you want to "initialize" it inside the `if` statement.  Delcaring is stating that there is a variable with such and such a name and such and such a type.  Initializing a variable is assigning it a value for the first time.  They are two very different things (even if it's common to do both in one line of code).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to be concise, you can replace the entire IF/ELSE block with the following line of code:

`var displayRectangle = new Rectangle(20, (text.Length > 80 ? 80 : 100), img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1);`

Comment: You can use `var` on the left hand side to make the line shorter. The compiler knows from the right hand side that the variable is of type `Rectangle`.  
  
The `Rectangle` constructor doesn't need a `new Point` and `new Size` object, it's easier to just pass in the values directly.  
  
The ternary operator `(condition) ? true-value : false-value` evaluates to one of the values provided depending on the truth of the condition. It's like a mini IF inside the assignment.

(Forgive my formatting, for some reason both markdown double-space and "<br/>" aren't working...