# Declare int outside logic

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

Yesterday I just asking about [logic, if else error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076171/c-sharp-if-else-logic-error/14076578) . But When I do this with? **int** , its error...

```
        private static void mergeimagefile(string image1path, string image2path)
    {
        //get all the files in a directory
        string jpg1 = @image1path;
        string jpg2 = @image2path;
        string jpg3 = @image2path;


        Image img1 = Image.FromFile(jpg1);
        Image img2 = Image.FromFile(jpg2);

        //int width = img1.Width + img2.Width;
        int width = 640;
        //int height = Math.Max(img1.Height, img2.Height);
        int height = 360;
        int w;

        if (img2.Width > 640) {
            w = 640;
        }
        else if (img2.Width <= 640)
        {
            w = ((width - img2.Width) / 2);
        }
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(w.ToString());

        int h = new int();
        if (img2.Height > 360)
        {
            h = 360;
        }
        else if (img2.Height <= 360)
        {
            h = (height - img2.Height) / 2;
        }


        Bitmap img3 = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img3);

        g.Clear(Color.Black);
        g.DrawImage(img1, new Point(0, 0));
        //ERROR IN HERE
        g.DrawImage(img2, new Point(w, h));

        g.Dispose();
        img1.Dispose();
        img2.Dispose();

        img3.Save(jpg3, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        img3.Dispose();

    }
```

I have tried adding, `int?` , `int w = null;` , and according [this Msdn Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx), its still gave me error?

> Error  1   Use of unassigned local variable 'w'    C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\template\template\Form1.cs 68  50  template

How to make this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a value so initialise it as 0.

```
int w = 0;
```

The reason you need to do this is that if you don't match either of these values

```
if (img2.Width > 640)
{
    w = 640;
}
else if (img2.Width <= 640)
{
    w = ((width - img2.Width) / 2);
}
```

then `w` will be unassigned.

Also assign `h` in the same way since `int h = new int();` is not an approach you would use for initialising an integer.

Comment: I checked with breakpoint... (img2.Width <= 640) == true :)

Comment: @radiaku the problem is because of the `else if` the compiler thinks that it is possible that neither `if` is matched, `w` would be unassigned.

Comment: and how to make this right?

Comment: @radiaku initialise it with a value `int w = 0;` see the first line of my answer!

Comment: after debugging that, I found... something stupid behind my code... -_-" the image was same size with bg, that make math keep getting me 0 value..., thanks btw.. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
int w = 0;
```

That should take care of initialization errror.

Comment: but value remain not changed? any hand?

Comment: Your code looks correct, although unnecessary complex. I would suggest setting the value of w to 640 during initialization, and then just use second if statement

Answer (score 1):

`int? w = null; Represents a value type that can be assigned null.`[enter link description here][1] why not just initialize the int w = 0 or

if you want to get fancy do

```
int w = default(int); //this is equiv to saying int w = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler thinks that the value of `w` could be undefined after the `if` statements. It's not built clever enough to recognise that the conditions actually covers all situations.

The second `if` statement is superfluous as it will always be true if the first condition is false. Just remove the second `if` statement and put the code in the `else`:

```
if (img2.Width > 640) {
  w = 640;
} else {
  w = ((width - img2.Width) / 2);
}
```

Now the compiler can easily see that the variable always gets a value.